# How can I change an alert window to a printout on the page by document.write method?

Tags: javascript

I want to change the alert windows to printouts on the page of the clues that tell the user if the number entered is less than or greater than the random number.

```
    var random = Math.round(Math.random()*100);

    var mynum, attempts;

    mynum = 0;
    
    attempts= 0;

    do {

        mynum = prompt("Enter a nº from 0 to 100");

        if (random > mynum) {

        alert("Higher!");//I try to change the alert to document.write and the program stops working

        }

        if (random < mynum) {

        alert("Lower!");//Here  

        }

        attempts++;

    } while (random!= mynum);


    alert("Correct! " + "You made: " + attempts + " attempts" + ".");//And here
```

Answer (score -1):

You are missing to create random.

```js
function generateRandom() {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
}

function gameStart() {
  const target = generateRandom();
  let userNumber = null;
  let attempts = 0;
  do {
    userNumber = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number from 0 to 100"));

    if (target > userNumber) {
      alert("Higher!");
    } else {
      alert("Lower!");
    }

    attempts++;
  } while (userNumber !== target);

  //alert("Correct! " + "You made: " + attempts + " attempts" + ".");
  //it's seems more readable
  alert(`Correct! You made: ${attempts} attempts.`);
}

gameStart();
```